# Can't pass data between controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, I am trying to globally store and pass data from one controller to another via a service. I stored the data in one controller and confirmed that it was stored at the beginning of my `buildReportController`. Then, when I click a button on my UI, it opens `reportResultsController`. However, issue is, I can store the data correctly in `buildReportController` via `locationHistoryService.store()` but when I go to `reportResultsController and call`locationHistoryService.get()`, the`previousLocation`variable in`locationHistoryService` is empty as if the data was never set. Any ideas on how why or how I can "globally" store data and pass it between controllers? Below is my attempt. Thanks!

In reportView.js

```
angular.module('reportView', [])
    .service('locationHistoryService', function(){
        var previousLocation = "";
        return {
            store: function(location){
                previousLocation = location;
            },

            get: function(){
                return previousLocation;
            }
        };
});
```

In buildReport.js

```
angular.module('buildReport', ['reportView'])
    .controller('buildReportController', ['$rootScope', 'locationHistoryService'], function($rootScope, locationHistoryService){
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e, newLocation, oldLocation){
            locationHistoryService.store(oldLocation);
            console.log("Old location: ", oldLocation);
        });
}
```

In reportResults.js

```
angular.module('reportResults', ['reportView'])
    .controller('reportResultsController', ['$rootScope', 'locationHistoryService'], function($rootScope, locationHistoryService){
    console.log("location : ", locationHistoryService.get());
}
```

Comment: Can you try by changing the function names of the service some thing like instead of ``store`` use ``setPrevLocation`` and instead of just ``get`` use ``getprevLocation``.   ``get`` might be a keyword or some reserver word though not sure.

Comment: You tried change service by factory?

Answer (score 0):

The `locationHistoryService.get()` method in reportResults.js is called before it is set in buildReport.js.

It would be better if you announce when the previousLocation variable has been set.

In reportView.js

```
angular.module('reportView', [])
    .service('locationHistoryService',['$rootScope'] ,function($rootScope){
        var previousLocation = "";
        return {
            store: function(location){
                previousLocation = location;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('previous-location-set');
            },

            get: function(){
                return previousLocation;
            }
        };
});
```

In reportResults.js

```
angular.module('reportResults', ['reportView'])
    .controller('reportResultsController', ['$rootScope', 'locationHistoryService'], function($rootScope, locationHistoryService){
    $rootScope.$on('previous-location-set', function(){
      console.log("location : ", locationHistoryService.get());          
    });
}
```

Comment: Hm, well the thing is, I go to the  html page that has the `ng-controller` set to `buildReportController` first and it is set there. Then, on the UI, I have a button that leads me to the `reportResult`s html page which has a `ng-controller` set to `reportResultsController` but I guess I am wrong. One question about your solution: isn't `$broadcast` used to fire parent -> child? Wouldn't I want to use `$emit` instead? Also for your solution when do I `store()` the `previousLocation`?

Comment: `$broadcast` and `$emit` make sense when you talk about local `$scopes` since `$rootScope` is the same for all controllers and services, you can use either of them. You can `store()` the previous location the same way you did last time (in buildReport.js)

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately, the $on was never called

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp should have only one module which is automatically bootstrapped by angular, and other modules as dependencies. The syntax of writing service is incorrect. You wrote `.service` but returning object which `.factory` should return. Here is working example of your code http://codepen.io/Chyngyz/pen/NxbdpW?editors=101

Also you wrote the **safe for minification syntax** of controllers incorrect, the function block of controller should be the last item in the array.